# Symfony 1 not autoloading model classes

Tags: php, class, symfony1, model, autoload

An older Symfony project does not load **some** of the model classes. The model generates ok and i can see the classes in project/lib/model but when i refresh the page i get "Unknown model class MyClass" exception. I tryied to clear the cache.

I checked the config_autoload.yml.php file in the cache folder and these classes are not present. But many other are...

So my question is: Why does the symfony autoloader ignore these files only and what can i do to overcome this.

Symfony version is 1.0.22

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it's a php restriction.. How many table do you have in your model?

Comment: About 35. What restriction could that be? I certanly had more than this :(

Comment: Are you using doctrine or propel ? Is it always the same model that are loaded, I mean, symfony stop every time at the same amount of model?

Comment: No. I found a solution: I deleted the file, rebuild the model then copied back the code.  And...know it works. Not really shure what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:
delete the content of cache folder from explorer.

Solution 2:
issue the command from the root of the project. "symfony cc or symfony clear:cache"